# Magento2: custom validation Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Tags: magento2, error, rules, custom-validation

In my custom validation rules shows '

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined'
>   errors!!!...

.  how can i do custom logic and proper validation ?

**Here is my Code**

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html

```
       <input class="input-text"
               type="text"
               data-bind="
                    textInput: email,
                    hasFocus: emailFocused,
                    mageInit: {'mage/trim-input':{}}"
               name="username"
               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-custom-key':true}"
               id="customer-email" />
```

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
// JavaScript Document
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            script: 'Vendor_Module/js/script'
        },
        '*': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/action/login': 'Vendor_Module/js/action/login'
        },
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/form/element/email.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/form/element/email.html'
        }
    }, mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/validator-mixin': true
        }
    }
};
```

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/js/validator-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-custom-key',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

> jquery.validate.js:556 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call of undefined
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

use **addRule** instead of **addMethod**.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (validator) {
        validator.addRule(
            'validate-custom-key',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
        return validator;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply ,But it shows same error

Comment: Delete static content and redeploy. This should work.

Comment: i'm removed all cache/generate.static folder and deploy and ran all commands also ! but nothing changes , could you please check my files and codes , please

Comment: Hi @ShafeelSha Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hello @SohelRana sir I am facing the same issue, Can you please advise ?

Comment: I want to add custom validation rule for Street 1 on Checkout page... I tried several ways but no luck.. @SohelRana your advice will be really helpful!

Comment: @Aditya Shah , Sorry I'm helpless brother

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach validator using `data-validate` on input element, you have to:

1. This js file content seems to be alright.
2. In requirejs config add it like this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        'Vendor_Module/js/validator': true // removed "mixin" from file name as it is not a mixin anymore
    }
}
```

3. In HTML somewhere after input element you need to add something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/js/validator": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way jquery attaches this validator and will be able to use it. You can read more about attaching validator this way here:
https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/add-custom-validation-rule-in-magento-2/ (I'm not the author of this article, I just used it to solve the same problem you encountered).

If you want to use mixin, then you might need to attach this validator using PHP or XML.